# How much voltage does a 12V led strip need to light up?

Tags: voltage, led, dc, 12v

I'm designing a photovoltaic powered installation. In my current design, I'm using a 12V battery, and I intended to power the lighting directly at that voltage without the usage of an inverter.

I understand that at 12V voltage drops quickly with distance unless thick wires are used. I wanted to know how much voltage I can afford to drop in order for the led lighting to still work.

The problem is the technical specifications of lighting only say "12v", and I find it impossible for them to require exactly 12V because it's not possible to have a 0 voltage drop.

So, looking for example at [this light](https://www.amazon.es/Shinning-star-industrial-exteriores-Resistente-impermeable/dp/B078T78TJ9/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1528739623&sr=8-3&keywords=foco%20led%2012v), what's the minimum voltage it will need to light up?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for specifications of an undocumented consumer product.  The lack of such information is the reason why questions on the use of consumer products are prohibited here.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I put that link just to give an example, but I was asking for a way to know the minimum voltage for a given LED light, assuming there is a way. The main point of the question wasn't related to that link anyways.

Comment: Poor quality light , no V tolerance specs , consider 16AWG for long distance , possibly regulated inside, bluish cool white

Comment: Ask buyer if you can use car battery 14.2V or better the voltage tolerance then you know if it is regulated

Comment: How much voltage does a 12V led strip need to light up? 12 volts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum voltage need to light up an LED depends on your definition of "light up". The manufacturer's data sheet for the LED should give you a curve indicating light output as a function of current. So, you can determine how much current you need to "light up" the LEDs.

Then you have to determine how much voltage you need to apply to achieve the desired level of current. You need to know the forward voltage of the LEDs at the desired current level as well as the value of any series resistor. Use Ohm's Law to calculate the voltage across the resistor, add the forward voltage of the LEDs, and you have the minimum required voltage
and current.

Obviously, this is very difficult if you buy something without the proper documentation. In that case you will need to do some experiments.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to depends on many things:  the length of your LED strip (how much wires in between LED's), the current consumption with each LED and the amount of current that your power supply can source.

At first glance, any led strip/device requires the rated voltage no more no less. Issue often arise when the current requested by all the strip is way above what the wire can safely take without inducing voltage loss.

You might think about increasing the voltage to counteract this effect of long LED strip with small wires, but it will not solve your issue completely. You run the risk of burning LED along the way or shorten their lifespan. Usually, the simplest approach would be to divide the LED into multiple shorter section and still provide it with 12v. This will reduce the wire voltage drop since the total current drawn per leg will be reduced. The only limitation become your power supply.

If you are using a per-packaged device (like the one you pointed out as an example), then the only thing you need to think about is your power source (yet again). Can it safely provide the required current for your device? If so, you're good to go.

Comment: So if using a per-packaged device it wouldn't matter if voltage drops from 12V to, say, 8V as long as there is enough current?

Comment: Not recommended but...a few things might occur: 1) a decreased voltage will most likely reduce the light output. They will be less bright overall. 2) The wires might begin to heat up since they were clearly not big enough to take the requested amount of current. 

You can take a look at this: https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm In your case, you want to respect the max amp per chassis wiring. You can also calculate the resistance of your wire based on the length. The power dissipated inside the wires is given by P = RI^2. This will give you a glimpse on why your wires might heat up.